# Does QueueBackgroundWorkItem actually queue background work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

We're running an ASP.NET WebAPI 2 service and we want to log some requests with our logger to email/database.

Because it's background work, and because in asp.net I figured we should use `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` to run it in the background.

I want my logs to all be in order - to my surprise I could not find anything indicating that `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` actually guarantees that the queued work items run in order or indicates it doesn't.

So, my question is: Does `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` guarantee that work queued gets executed in order?

```
 HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem((e) => Console.WriteLine("A")); 
 HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem((e) => Console.WriteLine("B"));
```

Do I know that the output of the above snippet is always:

```
A
B
```

Or can it be out of order?

Comment: I think you should use `Queue` object for your purpose

Comment: Why are you using QBWI at first place ? If your hosting decides to recycle ,and the operation is not finished through 30 sec  for some reason, it will terminate it. DON'T use that. [Additionalinformation here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html). If you really want  Queue based Task mechanism  - you'll have to implement it by yourself.

Comment: @RoyiNamir 30 seconds is a lot more than I need and it supports cancellation. Failure is always an option in computing and I just watch the cancel token and when I see it I push the message in a queue.

Comment: Cancellation is when _you_ want to cancel it. That's one thing. I was talking about a situation where you assume your task would work  , and actually it won't ( due to recycle or other stuff , beyond the 30 seconds , But if you're fine with that limit  - Then you're set) .

Comment: @RoyiNamir cancellation is when _someone_ wants to cancel it. In this case, cancellation is initiated by the framework and not by you - you just react to it with the token. In order to initiate cancellation you need a token source - `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` takes a token. (Although _technically_ you can kill the process which would do cause QueueBackgroundWorkItems' tokens to change to cancelled)

Comment: @RoyiNamir QueueBackgroundWorkItem has an overload that takes a cancel token. So even if I'm close to being out of time - I can still log the work to be done later outside of asp.net. This is not unique to QueueBackgroundWorkItem - all code needs to be resilient to the server stopping and hopefully atomic enough so that the server stopping unexpectedly won't bug it.

Comment: Agree. I  said it to watch out for the 30 sec boundary .BTW - why did you want to log it as order while you could add a datetime to the SP ? and then order it via `order by` ? (ref: _I want my logs to all be in order_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be nothing contractual in the documentation.

Looking at the reference source, it appears to use a class called [`BackgroundWorker`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Hosting/BackgroundWorkScheduler.cs,a9ddece7a1bd4bb3) to actually execute these tasks.

In turn, this appears to be running the tasks on the `ThreadPool` and explicitly may be executing multiple tasks in parallel:

```
    public void ScheduleWorkItem(Func<CancellationToken, Task> workItem) {
        Debug.Assert(workItem != null);

        if (_cancellationTokenHelper.IsCancellationRequested) {
            return; // we're not going to run this work item
        }

        // Unsafe* since we want to get rid of Principal and other constructs specific to the current ExecutionContext
        ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem(state => {
            lock (this) {
                if (_cancellationTokenHelper.IsCancellationRequested) {
                    return; // we're not going to run this work item
                }
                else {
                    _numExecutingWorkItems++;
                }
            }

            RunWorkItemImpl((Func<CancellationToken, Task>)state);
        }, workItem);
    }
```

So I'd say it's unsafe to assume anything about what order two queued tasks will *complete* in.

Answer (score -1):

QueueBackgroundWorkItem guarantee that work queued gets executed in order

Reference from [HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem](http://www.davidwhitney.co.uk/Blog/2014/05/09/exploring-the-queuebackgroundworkitem-in-asp-net-framework-4-5-2/)

> New HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem method that lets you schedule small background work items. ASP.NET tracks these items and prevents IIS from abruptly terminating the worker process until all background work items have completed. These will enable ASP.NET applications to reliably schedule Async work items.

Comment: I see nothing in that quote nor in the whole article that specifies the *order* in which tasks will be executed, which appears to be the point of this question.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  QueueBackgroundWorkItem will execute the same way as the queue tasks. it depends on the order of the tasks